# `to_i` method with base value as parameter in ruby

Tags: ruby

Can anyone explain how base parameter works when calling `to_i` with the following examples?

```
'2'.to_i(2) #=> 0
'3'.to_i(2) #=> 0
'12'.to_i(2) #=> 1
'122'.to_i(2) #=> 1
'20'.to_i(2) #=> 0
'21'.to_i(2) #=> 0
```

I do not understand how it's actually working. Can anyone explain please?

Comment: `"2".to_i #=> 2`, `2.to_s(2) #=> "10"`, `"10".to_i(2) #=> 2`; `2.to_s #=> "2"`.

Comment: this is a case where you should be using `Integer(x, 2)` instead of `x.to_i(2)`. The latter will never throw an error, but it's also probably not doing what you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is the same reason that `'54thousand'.to_i` is `54`: `to_i` reads until it finds end of string or an invalid digit.

In binary (base 2), the only valid digits are `0` and `1`. Thus, because `2` is invalid, `'122'.to_i(2)` is identical to `'1'.to_i(2)`. Also, `'2'.to_i(2)` is identical to `''.to_i(2)`, which is rather intuitively `0`.

Comment: This behaviour is described in [`String#to_i`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-to_i) API docs. @2017kamb It's always a good idea to read API docs if You are confused about a method behaviour.

Comment: Conversely, `'54thousand'.to_i(36)` returns 521,395,291,927,273 because it actually interprets all characters as base 36 digits.

Answer (score 3):

`base`, in other word [Radix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix) means the number of unique digits in a numeral system.

In Decimal, we have `0` to `9`, 10 digits to represent numbers.
You are using `2` as parameter, that means [Binary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number), so there're only `0` and `1` working.

From the [Doc of to_i](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-to_i):

> Returns the result of interpreting leading characters in `str` as an
>   integer base base (between 2 and 36). Extraneous characters past the
>   end of a valid number are ignored. If there is not a valid number at
>   the start of `str`, `0` is returned. This method never raises an
>   exception when base is valid.

You can use these number representations directly in Ruby:

```
num_hex = 0x100
#=> 256
num_bin = 0b100
#=> 4
num_oct = 0o100
#=> 64
num_dec = 0d100
#=> 100
```